# pandas column selection fails with tuple column names from merged Excel columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe where the column names are tuples. The reason for this is that the dataframe is based on a complicated Excel spreadsheet where the column headers consist of merged cells of varying sizes, so in the MultiIndex nearly every column has one or more levels with nan entries which makes selecting and writing data hard. I have used the same solution without issue multiple times in the past, where for example, a MultiIndex header `('SCN', nan, nan, nan, nan)` will be turned into the tuple `('SCN',)` and then we change the MultiIndex to a normal Index of tuples. However, this time I can't seem to do much of anything to or with the dataframe due to strange KeyErrors and TypeErrors:

```
test.columns
Out[25]: 
Index([                                                    ('SCN',),
                                                          ('Site',),
                                                ('Subject Status',),
                                               ('Enrollment Date',),
                                               ('Enrollment Type',),
                                                 ('Specimen Type',),
                    ('Inclusion Criteria', 'Consented', 'Symptoms'),
                     ('Inclusion Criteria', 'Consented', 'Consent'),
                      ('Inclusion Criteria', 'Consented', 'Volume'),
                       ('Inclusion Criteria', 'Residual', 'Sample'),
       ...
                                ('PI Review', 'All Forms Complete'),
                                      ('PI Review', 'PI Signature'),
                                         ('Sunday of Enroll Week',),
                                           ('Sunday of Last Week',)],
      dtype='object', length=296)
```

trying to query:

```
test[('SCN',)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 126, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 169, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
KeyError: ('SCN',)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-26-5cd8b06f24ce>", line 1, in <module>
    test[('SCN',)]
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 126, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 169, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
KeyError: ('SCN',)
```

even more explicit:

```
test[test.columns[0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 126, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 169, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
KeyError: ('SCN',)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-27-d47929e28842>", line 1, in <module>
    test[test.columns[0]]
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 126, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 169, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
KeyError: ('SCN',)
```

Strangely, when passing a list of the tuples it works, but returns a single-column dataframe instead of a series as expected.

other columns give a different error:

```
test[test.columns[45]]
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:2897: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  return self._engine.get_loc(key)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-28-31714132fb16>", line 1, in <module>
    test[test.columns[45]]
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\project_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 126, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 160, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
TypeError: Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray
```

Any ideas what is going on here??
Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to make a smaller executable example out of this? Surely this is not the minimum amount of code needed to replicate the error. Also, did you try `test[('SCN',),:]`?

Comment: Please post reproducible code

Answer (score 1):

> I have a dataframe where the column names are tuples.

Don't. **Convert the column names to simple strings, already.** Something like:

```
df.columns = [cols[0] for cols in df.columns]
```

I'm not aware that pandas supports tuples as column names. Make your life easy.

`test[('SCN',)]` gives `KeyError: ('SCN',)`. Clearly pandas doesn't like tuples as column names. So don't do it.

Ok I now see some column-name tuples have length >1 e.g. `('Inclusion Criteria', 'Consented', 'Symptoms')`, and *"the dataframe is based on a complicated Excel spreadsheet where the column headers consist of merged cells of varying sizes"*. Just because Excel can export something (merged cells), is no expectation pandas supports it. Figure out empirically what schema pandas can support. At worst if you need to manually kludge the column names to `'Inclusion_Criteria_Consented_Symptoms'`, then do that.

Comment: Pandas does support tuples as column names. I have done it multiple times in the past. It has always worked very well for this particular application with the big excel spreadsheets. I am trying to figure out why it is breaking this time around. If I can't perhaps I will go to using underscores or some kind of structure with strings. Thanks

Comment: Ern: Please post reproducible code and I'll try to give a better answer